# Iterate through nested object. Only output object that require?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came from a more PHP Background where PHP have a foreach loop

Example of an object.

```
{
  "person": {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "title": "Miss",
      "first": "Emma",
      "last": "Hart"
    }
  }
}
```

A php example will be

```
$person = the_object;
$title = '';
$fName = '';
foreach($person['person'] as $key => $value){
  if($key == "name"){
   $fName = $value['first'];
  }
}
```

So i have saved first Name into a variable.

I tried running this

```
      async myFunc(){
    for (var key in this.state.person) {
        
        if(key === 'name'){
            console.log(key);
            this.setState({title: this.state.person[key]['title']})
        };
     }
  }
```

inside my class Component just before render. But nothing happen.

Assuming i already have a state call Person and the object have being set.
I can access on the render if `{this.state.person.gender}`

but i name the title it throws an error `{this.state.person.name.title}`

It throws an error regarding `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: The error is trying to `render` an object and not about `setState` function

Comment: @ISAE thank you for your reply. So i need to iterate through the object with map? But i just need the name

Comment: It looks like `name` itself is an object as it has the keys `{title, first, last}`, so yes, you'll need to iterate that. ( `Object.values(this.state.person.name)`  will do).

Comment: Inside my render `return (){<div> { Object.values(this.state.person.name)}     </div>
}`

I get an error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Will need to see more code in order to solve this. try to console.log name and see what u get.

Comment: @ISAE 
Console log this.state.person.name on my async ComponentDidMount()
{title: "Mr", first: "Susano", last: "Oliveira"}
first: "Susano"
last: "Oliveira"
title: "Mr"